# How to insert value of dynamically created input boxes into database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter

hello developers i am creating 2 text boxes and 1 select box dynamically using java script function... now i want to post the value of (n) fields created into database (relevant table)
as i am using codeigniter so m posting the script and code

this is the simple java script that i am using

```
<script>
  var counter=1;
  function generateRow() {
    var count="<font color='red'>"+counter+"</font>";
    var temp ="<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='stop"+counter+"' placeholder='Stop Name'></input></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='timing"+counter+"' placeholder='Timing'></input></div>&nbsp;<div class='_25'><select id='ampm"+counter+"' name='ampm"+counter+"'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>  </div>";

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = temp + count;

    var yourDiv = document.getElementById('div');
    yourDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
  }
</script>
```

and this is my division on php file

```
 <div id="div">
 </div>

 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div class="_25">
    <p>
      <input type="button" name="button" class="button red" id="button" value="Add"  onclick="generateRow() "/></a>
    </p>
 </div>
 <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
```

and this is my related table fields

```
route_number    stop_name   am_pm   timing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite way to do this is to use the DOM as much as possible. Don't use counters unless you absolutely have to (they're just a source of bugs). Here's a quick example:

Html/JS/jQuery (can vary, I crafted this to make it easy to follow):

```
<form method="POST" id="theForm">
    <div id="fields">
        <input type="text" name="fields[]"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="addField" value="Add Field"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#addField').click(function() {
            $('#fields').append(
                $('<input type="text" name="fields[]"/>')
            );
        })
    });
</script>
```

Note how I don't need to use any sort of counting variable. Just like PHP, you can create an array of POST variables without specifying indexes by using `[]` and the server (or browser? I'm not sure) will build the array for you. The order in which the `<input />` fields are rendered on the page will be the order they are provided to your PHP via `$_POST`. This code...

```
foreach ($_POST['fields'] as $fieldIndex => $fieldValue) {
    doStuff($fieldValue);
}
```

... will process each field in the order they were added. You can even use JavaScript to *re-order* or *remove* the inputs and that will be reflected in `$_POST`. This method, coupled with JSON encoding, makes for a fast and easy way to handle multi-input, free-form fields.

## Update:

Applying the above code to your use-case requires a small addition that may not be obvious. You'll need to create an array for each of the three inputs (stop, timing, and ampm) like so:

```
<form method="POST" id="theForm">
    <div id="fields">
        <input type="text" name="fields[stop][]"/>
        <input type="text" name="fields[timing][]"/>
        <select name="fields[ampm][]">
            <option value="am">AM</option>
            <option value="pm">PM</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="addField" value="Add Field"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#addField').click(function() {
            $('#fields').append(
                $('<input type="text" name="fields[stop][]"/>'),
                $('<input type="text" name="fields[timing][]"/>'),
                $('<select name="fields[ampm][]"><option value="am">AM</option><option value="pm">PM</option></select>'),
                $('<br/>')
            );
        })
    });
</script>
```

Filling out this form with some test data yields the following array:

```
[fields] => Array
(
    [stop] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaa
            [1] => bbb
        )

    [timing] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1111
            [1] => 2222
        )

    [ampm] => Array
        (
            [0] => am
            [1] => pm
        )

)
```

And to process that in PHP requires a simple old-school loop:

```
$numFields = count($_POST['fields']['stop']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) {

    // Pack the field up in an array for ease-of-use.
    $field = array(
        'stop' => $_POST['fields']['stop'][$i],
        'timing' => $_POST['fields']['timing'][$i],
        'ampm' => $_POST['fields']['ampm'][$i]
    );

    saveToDatabase($field);
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have time right now to make sure all that is correct. It should be,  and if its not it may still help :). I'll check back in a few hours.

Comment: Please note, that this answer is using `JQuery`.

Comment: @Manica thanx working wll

Comment: as ur code i have done it but still facing a problem on php end:

Comment: Could you update your question and add the form-processing php code?

Comment: @maniac : ya sure u can se that i am having more than 1 field in my javascript section, for the single textbox ur code is running but what about if the sets of 2 texboxes and 1 select box values are comming.. i want to insert there value in database fields too,so where to write insertion query ?

Comment: Ah, I think I see where you're getting hung up. I'll update my answer with something that may help.

Answer (score 0):

name your dynamic input box `"stop["+counter+"]"` (using braces as part of the name) instead of adding a counter to the end of the name. Then in your post data, `$_POST['stop']` will be an array of values that you can just foreach loop over with the counter as the key in the sub-array. And `$_POST['stop'][1]` will correspond to `$_POST['timing'][1]`...etc.

Comment: can u pleas tell me the php script to write in ordet to get data on server side ?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the following HTML `input` fields:

```
<input type="text" name="data[]" />
<input type="text" name="data[]" />
<input type="text" name="data[]" />
// ...
```

Which will lead to an array keyed `data` inside $_REQUEST super global, when you `var_dump($_REQUEST['data'])`. Try it out. You don't even need to index the `data[]` array, since PHP will do it for you.

You might want to process your `$_REQUEST['data']` or `$_POST['data']` array with a `foreach` loop construct:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['data'] as $data){
  // $data is the corresponding input field's value
}
```

Comment: yaa thanx @dyin  its working 
m gonna post working answer for this post